# Window Control doesn't work corectly on UBUNTU 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, unity-tweak-tool

Even if I select " Right Allign " on Window Control inside Unity Tweak Tool it doesn't work, and command controls remain only on the left side, even when I check the checkbox below " Show menu button "

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no hope for that: unfortunately, the new Unity decorations seems not to support changing the window buttons position (close, minimize, maximize), at least for now.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2210844&page=2#14

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2210844&page=4#39

https://code.launchpad.net/~3v1n0/unity/unity-decorations/+merge/202582

http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/unity-7-to-get-new-window-decorations.html